# include buttons in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I followed the instructions in this section:
[git buttons](https://github.com/thetron/css3buttons_rails_helpers)
I want to customize the application that follows the example guide rails

I'm trying to implement some cascading style sheets, css files in my application.
I followed the video "CSS3Buttons Gem" but although the buttons work. Now I can see some nice buttons in my application, the application also returns me an error:

When I write the instruction `rails g css3buttons` console I get this error "Could not find generator css3buttons." Any ideas?

Comment: what version of Rails are you using? The generator is for Rails 3.0.x only.

Comment: im using 4.0 because de guide, but something still work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to run `rails g css3buttons`?

In Rails 4 everything works without it:

Gemfile

```
#get latest available version from GitHub instead of RubyGems
gem 'css3buttons', '~> 1.0.1', git: 'https://github.com/StevenNunez/css3buttons_rails_helpers'
```

In root folder run `bundle install`

Add `*= require css3buttons` on top of others in 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.css'

Add `<%= css3buttons_stylesheets %>` in 'app/veiws/layouts/application.html.erb' in `<head>` section

Enjoy.

Comment: that's what I did. Guess that's why "work" buttons. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The generator you listed is to be used for Rails 3.0 apps only (ie. apps that do not use the asset pipeline that was introduced in Rails 3.1).

It doesn't look like the gem has been touched in over two years, so it's last compatibility check was for Rails 3.1. If it works in Rails 4 that's a happy bonus, but if it has problems, you may be out of luck.

Comment: some things work, others do not. For example: when I try to add the `` add_button_link_to not see the + symbol, or when I try to adjust several buttons so that they appear in a line does not work.
But I prefer to limit to use rails 4.0.0. I'm a newbie and if I start to switch between versions of a mess I'll `rails rvm use-v`